# What if a person is high in warmth but low in empathy?

Tags: personality, personality-disorder

From these definitions ([1](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-extraversion), [2](http://www.testsonthenet.com/Factors-facets.htm#Extraversion), [3](http://www.timothy-judge.com/documents/2013-31562-001.pdf), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_NEO_Personality_Inventory)) I have concluded that **warmth** is a facet that describes how much a person is showing warmth and love towards other people (e.g., touching, kissing, saying nice things) and **empathy** is how much a person sympathizes with the feelings of other people.

What if you are high in **warmth** but low in **empathy**? How would such a person behave? Isn't those facets are somewhat opposite of one another?

Comment: Your links talk about extraversion which is different to warmth and empathy and [empathy is not be confused with sympathy](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21258/7604). Do you have examples of how someone could be high in warmth but low in empathy?